# Making hashes find each other by their values using Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, logic

I have a couple `time_tables` in this array. There are four `time_tables` that are related to each other in a linear way by their `start_location - end_location` and `start_date - end_date`.

When the first `time_table` ends, the other `time_table` starts, and so on.

My code:

```
arr =   [
      { name: 01, start_date: '2014-04-24 22:03:00', start_location: 'A', end_date: '2014-04-24 22:10:00', end_location: 'B' },
      { name: 05, start_date: '2014-04-24 22:10:00', start_location: 'C', end_date: '2014-04-24 23:10:00', end_location: 'D' },
      { name: 01, start_date: '2014-04-24 17:10:00', start_location: 'X', end_date: '2014-04-24 20:10:00', end_location: 'B' },
      { name: 01, start_date: '2014-04-24 17:10:00', start_location: 'Z', end_date: '2014-04-24 20:10:00', end_location: 'B' },
      { name: 06, start_date: '2014-04-24 20:15:00', start_location: 'B', end_date: '2014-04-24 22:10:00', end_location: 'C' },
      { name: 03, start_date: '2014-04-24 23:15:00', start_location: 'D', end_date: '2014-04-24 00:10:00', end_location: 'E' }
    ]
new_array = []

i = 0
while i <= 5 do
  if arr[i][:end_location] == arr[i+1][:start_location] && arr[i][:start_date] <= arr[i+1][:start_date]
    new_array << arr[i+1]
  end
  i = i + 1
end
```

This is the result that I want:

```
  # My expexpected result will be this:
  #     [
  #     { name: 01, start_date: '2014-04-24 22:03:00', start_location: 'A', end_date: '2014-04-24 22:10:00', end_location: 'B' },
  #    { name: 06, start_date: '2014-04-24 22:15:00', start_location: 'B', end_date: '2014-04-24 22:20:00', end_location: 'C' },
  #    { name: 05, start_date: '2014-04-24 22:20:00', start_location: 'C', end_date: '2014-04-24 23:10:00', end_location: 'D' },
  #    { name: 03, start_date: '2014-04-24 23:15:00', start_location: 'D', end_date: '2014-04-24 00:10:00', end_location: 'E' }
  # 

  ]
```

but my algorithm is seems to be bad. Thank you for insights to make this work.

Comment: I don't understand.  Please explain how the start and end dates for the second element of the expected result (`name: 06`) were determined.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Hi CAry! tried to run yr email rubycode, it wont run :)

Comment: Hmmm.  It seems OK, but it's my first name at my last name, dot com, if you'd like to email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you really looking for the longest linear sub sequent time tables ? I wanted to clarify that through comments but I didn't have the permission to comment. Also there is a difference between the value of start_date of B (and start_location B) in input and the output, so I'm assuming it's a mistake.

I have written the solution considering you want to find the longest linear sub sequent time tables.

```
require 'date'

def getLLTT(time_tables)

    longest = []
    time_tables.sort_by! do |time_table|
        DateTime.parse(time_table[:start_date]).to_time
    end

    0.upto(time_tables.size-1) do |i|

        long_for_i = [time_tables[i]]
        0.upto(i-1) do |j|
            j_end_date = DateTime.parse(longest[j][-1][:end_date]).to_time
            i_start_date = DateTime.parse(time_tables[i][:start_date]).to_time
            if j_end_date <= i_start_date 
                if longest[j][-1][:end_location].eql? time_tables[i][:start_location]
                    if longest[j].size + 1 > long_for_i.size
                        long_for_i = longest[j] + [time_tables[i]]
                    end
                end
            end
        end

        longest[i] = long_for_i
    end
    return longest[-1]
end

puts getLLTT(arr)
```

So given the input :

```
arr =   [
{ name: 01, start_date: '2014-04-24 22:03:00', start_location: 'A', end_date: '2014-04-24 22:10:00', end_location: 'B' },
  { name: 05, start_date: '2014-04-24 22:10:00', start_location: 'C', end_date: '2014-04-24 23:10:00', end_location: 'D' },
  { name: 01, start_date: '2014-04-24 17:10:00', start_location: 'X', end_date: '2014-04-24 20:10:00', end_location: 'B' },
  { name: 01, start_date: '2014-04-24 17:10:00', start_location: 'Z', end_date: '2014-04-24 20:10:00', end_location: 'B' },
  { name: 06, start_date: '2014-04-24 20:15:00', start_location: 'B', end_date: '2014-04-24 22:10:00', end_location: 'C' },
  { name: 03, start_date: '2014-04-24 23:15:00', start_location: 'D', end_date: '2014-04-24 00:10:00', end_location: 'E' }
]
```

The output will be :

```
[
{:name=>1, :start_date=>"2014-04-24 17:10:00", :start_location=>"Z", :end_date=>"2014-04-24 20:10:00", :end_location=>"B"}
{:name=>6, :start_date=>"2014-04-24 20:15:00", :start_location=>"B", :end_date=>"2014-04-24 22:10:00", :end_location=>"C"}
{:name=>5, :start_date=>"2014-04-24 22:10:00", :start_location=>"C", :end_date=>"2014-04-24 23:10:00", :end_location=>"D"}
{:name=>3, :start_date=>"2014-04-24 23:15:00", :start_location=>"D", :end_date=>"2014-04-24 00:10:00", :end_location=>"E"}
]
```

Comment: @YoniGeek : It holds the longest sequence found up to every index, for instance longest[i] holds the longest array of time tables upto i. Now for every i of the outer loop, the inner loop iterates from 0 to i-1, finding the longest valid sequence (end of which relates with i by the given condition) of time tables found in 'longest[]' for indexes before i and then it adds it with time table of i and stores it in 'longest[i]'. So by the end of the iteration of the outer loop, 'longest[time_tables.size-1]' will hold the longest linear subsequent time tables up to the last index.

Comment: but where is longest[]-array being filled? it's empty from the beginning and suddenly get the content of Timetable-array. one more question:  what are u trying to do here: 'if longest[j].size + 1 > long_for_i.size'

Comment: It's filled at longest[i] = long_for_i, last statement of the outer loop. And about that, it checks if previously found longest array for index j added to the current time table ( table at i) is greater than the longest one found so far for the index i.  It's used to get the longest one from the ones found before for indexes 0 to i-1 that can be connected sequentially with the time table at index i.

Comment: nice, sorry if Im asking u a lot... Im new to Ruby. What is this '-1' doing here:  "longest[j][-1][:end_date]" dont get it :( Is it the last item in the 'longest-array' ?

Comment: No problem. Yeah, -1 gets the last element of an array, -2 the second last and so on. But in that line, it gets the last element of the array stored in longest[j]. The longest array will look like [[a,b],[c,f,j]], so longest[0] gives [a,b], now longest[0][-1] gives b. But in the code it will be time tables instead of a,b,c etc used for the example.

Comment: thanks! one more last question: if this If-statement is true: "if longest[j].size + 1 > long_for_i.size" what does it actually mean? Im seeing yr adding '+1'  The code still works without this line though :) technically speaking what are we looking for? thanks!

Comment: The part "longest[j].size+1" means the size of the longest time table linear sequence found for index j added with the sizecurrent time table (which is always 1). Yeah you are right :), it works without that line for the input in the question. It's because that input after sorted naturally gives the longest list with just computing from the previous index. But there are other cases where it won't give the correct answer without that line.

Comment: Note that you don't need to convert the date-time strings to `Time` objects; just compare the strings. Date-time strings are often expressed in the "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" format for that very reason. Btw, shouldn't the end date for the last element of `arr` be "2014-04-25"? (I would ask the OP but he/she did not answer another question I left.)

Comment: @llkin what do u mean by this: longest linear sub sequent time table? the one that have many items inside?

Answer (score 0):

This will "join" your time series by consecutive end and start location.

```
 def span x; x[:end_location].ord - x[:start_location].ord; end
 def diff x, y; x[:start_location].ord - y[:start_location].ord; end
 arr = arr.sort_by { |x| [x[:start_location], span(x)] }
 prev = arr[0]
 arr = arr.slice_before { |e|
   prev, prev2 = e, prev
   diff(prev, prev2) != 0
 }.to_a.map(&:first).chunk(&method(:span)).first[1]
```

For example, I get

```
 arr.map { |x| [x[:start_location], x[:end_location] }
 => [["A", "B"], ["B", "C"], ["C", "D"], ["D", "E"]]
```

Comment: wow...thanks for give some ideas but I hardly understand some code.... :( what kind of method is this: '.ord' what is span-method and diff-method doing? in this line: prev, prev2 = e, prev, thanks 4 yr time!

Comment: Boy, that's the worst example of ruby code I've ever seen.